# populate sheet based on data criteria on another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

so, I have a worksheet like:
[data source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIIHt.png)

This is sheet "All".  What I want to do is on sheet "5 in" have all rows where all!H6:Hn > 0.  In other words, a sheet that extracts all of the "5 in" that are in inventory.  it would need to recalculate each time the sheet is opened. All data is in and below Row 6, above that is header info.

example output for the above would be:
[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OW5aY.png)
notice Ashly the Apple is missing as she's not in stock.

would prefer to use excel functions (using excel 365) unless vb will be only way to work it.

Any help is appreciated.  :D

Comment: Easily done with `Filter`

Comment: Have you tried anything? If not kindly try and let us know if any issues... we would glad to help you :)

Comment: Chris - had to teach myself syntax for advanced filter and then realized that to impliment it the way I want would require macros.  Still testing how that will share out.

Comment: Linga - I tried a few options before coming here (v and h lookup and Index) but the syntax is a problem since the column with the criteria is not to the left (can't change column orders)